# QGIS Layer won't load

Tags: qgis

If I try to load the following data using the Open Oracle Layer in QGIS, the layer is disabled and QGIS won't load it :

```
insert into rLINES( id, geom) select 1, SDO_GEOMETRY( 2002, NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY( 1,2,1), 
        SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY( 195421.075730808, 326086.472701877, 
                            195431.899003386, 326086.909972049, 
                            195441.359009782, 326088.651032466 )) from dual;
```

If I use this data, QGIS will display it :

```
insert into RLINES( id, geom) select 1, SDO_GEOMETRY( 2002, NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY( 1,2,1), 
        SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY( 10, 10, 
                            15, 15, 
                            20, 20 )) from dual;
```

Why is that ?

If I exit QGis and then start it again, the data is displayed.

Comment: what projection do you apply to the layer?

Comment: When loading I select EPSG:4289

Comment: I noticed that QGis also doesn't show Arcs, no matter if I put them in the second way of entering data or the first way. The same Arcs display just fine when I use Georaptor